# Pointer to the result of an operation

Tags: c++, pointers

I am looking for a way to access the result of an arithmetic operation through a pointer.

```
int  source1 = 5;
int  source2 = 4;
int* pResult = { &source1 + &source2; } //Something in that sense.
```

As far as I understand the way pointers work, accessing two addresses at once and performing an operation with the values stored at those addresses is simply not what pointers can do. I decided to use the example with a pointer to simply give an idea of what I want to do using a different approach (probably an STL type that I don't know yet).

Alternatively, I wouldn't mind creating a custom type/struct that is based on a `get` function. With my current understanding of C++, I don't know how to do that, however.

Comment: `auto adder = [&](){return source1 + source2;};` makes `adder` a _function_, which when called will return a result. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @MooingDuck Probably yes. Is `adder` a lambda expression? Since I haven't come across these in a greater detail yet, I do not know how to use them.

Comment: Yes, it's a lambda. Lambdas are uniquely typed, but can be referenced by `std::function<int()>`.

Comment: @MooingDuck I've just tested it, and it works perfect. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to do something more complicated than necessary.  But here's an example of how we can access "two addresses at once and performing an operation with the values stored at those addresses."

```
int  source1 = 5;
int  source2 = 4;
int *psource1 = &source1;
int *psource2 = &source2;
int  Result = *psource1 + *psource2;
```